# async/await functions using sqlite3

Tags: javascript, sqlite, async-await

I am trying to fetch all the data from a db table and I can't see the result. This is my code:

main code:

```
var tetera_raw = require('./file');

async function updating_db(tetera_raw){
    const obj_tetera = await tetera_raw.tetera_raw()
    .then(te =>{
        console.log(te)
        return te
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    console.log(obj_tetera)
    
};

updating_db(tetera_raw);
```

query code:

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose()

async function tetera_raw(){

    var tetera_new_raw = {}

    let db = new sqlite3.Database('databasename.db', (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log("Connection to the db FAILED");
        }
    })
    db.all("SELECT * FROM tetera", function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log("something went wrong with the query")
        }
        rows.forEach((row) =>{
            //console.log(row)
            tetera_new_raw[row.producto] = tetera_new_raw[row.precio]
        })
    })
    return tetera_new_raw;
};

module.exports.tetera_raw = tetera_raw
```

Most of the cases I get {} or undefined. with the console.log( inside of the forEach I am able to see the results of the query :-(

Comment: Have you tried any ORM like https://sequelize.org/ ?

Comment: not really, could you elaborate? I am kind of new into this :-(

Comment: what technology are you using ,  node , express ?

Comment: Node, sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: you can use an ORM like [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) that will help you to perform all these procedures

Comment: you have repository in gitHub, to see in a better way @error404